# Slider appears as images

Tags: magento-1.8, theme

See what is happening:
[image]
It is a slider so it should actually be just size of a image and not one after another.

Here is my code of home `content`:

```
Home Page



{{block type=\\\’core/template\\\’ template=\\\’pagayo/home.phtml\\\’}} {{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider1"}}

{{block type=\\\’core/template\\\’ template=\\\’pagayo/home.phtml\\\’}} {{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider2"}}

{{block type=\\\’core/template\\\’ template=\\\’pagayo/home.phtml\\\’}} {{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider3"}}
```

Here is `Design` code:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider1"}}
<reference name=\\\"content\\\"> 
<block type=\\\"catalog/product_list\\\" name=\\\"featured\\\" template=\\\"catalog/product/list.phtml\\\"> 
<action method=\\\"setCategoryId\\\"><category_id>pt001-home-slider1</category_id></action> 
<action method=\\\"setColumnCount\\\"><count>5</count></action> 
</block> 
</reference>
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider2"}}
<reference name=\\\"content\\\"> 
<block type=\\\"catalog/product_list\\\" name=\\\"featured\\\" template=\\\"catalog/product/list.phtml\\\"> 
<action method=\\\"setCategoryId\\\"><category_id>pt001-home-slider2</category_id></action> 
<action method=\\\"setColumnCount\\\"><count>5</count></action> 
</block> 
</reference>
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="pt001-home-slider3"}}
<reference name=\\\"content\\\"> 
<block type=\\\"catalog/product_list\\\" name=\\\"featured\\\" template=\\\"catalog/product/list.phtml\\\"> 
<action method=\\\"setCategoryId\\\"><category_id>pt001-home-slider3</category_id></action> 
<action method=\\\"setColumnCount\\\"><count>5</count></action> 
</block> 
</reference>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i think you have called the slider thrice, instead of calling one slider with 3 images.

Comment: @Helphin how to include 3 images in one and do it?

Comment: just follow the answer

Answer (score 2):

just call,

```
  {{block type="core/template" template="pagayo/home.phtml"}}
```

in your page,

this `home.phtml` calls your CMS/Blocks thrice, so the three images calls in this slider,
check the code inside the class `scroller`,

```
<div class="homepage">

    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slidercontrolwr-left">
            <div class="slidercontrol">
                <a href="#" class="aprev" title="Previous" onClick="my_glider.previous();return false;">Previous</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slidercontrolwr-right">
            <div class="slidercontrol">
                <a href="#" class="anext" title="Next" onClick="my_glider.next();return false">next</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="scroller">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="section" id="section1">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt001-home-slider1')->toHtml() ?>
                </div>
                <div class="section" id="section2">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt001-home-slider2')->toHtml() ?>
                </div>
                <div class="section" id="section3">
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt001-home-slider3')->toHtml() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/') ?>glider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var my_glider = new Glider('slider', {duration:0.5, autoGlide: true, frequency: 4, initialSection: 'section1'});
    </script>

    <div class="home-box1">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt003-home-box1')->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="home-box2">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt003-home-box2')->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="home-box3">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt003-home-box3')->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="home-box4">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('pt003-home-box4')->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearer"></div>

</div>
```